# SQLBuilder + Codeigniter v.4.1.1

Tags: php, codeigniter

Eu tenho um modelo chamado UsuarioModel que só funciona a opção find e findAll, porém no meu teste passo um where então o método não conecta na base: abaixo segue a chamada da funcao e o resultado:

Modelo:

```
class UsuarioModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'usuarios';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $allowedFields = ['nome', 'login', 'senha', 'tipoUsuario'];
    
    protected $returnType     = 'array';
    protected $useSoftDeletes = true;
    
    protected $useTimestamps = true;
    protected $createdField  = 'created_at';
    protected $updatedField  = 'updated_at';
    protected $deletedField  = 'deleted_at';
    
        
    public function get($id = null)
    {
        if($id <> null)
        {
            return $this->find($id);                    
        }           
        $exibe = $this->find();
        var_dump($exibe);
        exit();     
        
    }   
    
    public function pesquisar($busca = null)
    {
        
        $exibe = $this->where('id', 1);         
        var_dump($exibe);
        exit();
    }       
}
```

Controller:

```
class Usuario extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->model = new UsuarioModel();
    }   
    
    public function index()
    {   
        $busca = $this->request->getVar('busca');       
        if(!empty($busca))
        {           
            $this->data =   [
                'table' => $this->model->pesquisar($busca)
            ];
        }
        else
        {
            $this->data = [
                'table' => $this->model->get()
            ];
        }

        
        echo view('template/header');
        echo view('usuario/index', $this->data);
        echo view('template/footer');
    }
}
```

Comment: você fala o método `pesquisar`?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Esse é o resultado do var_dump do método pesquisar: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/XypRnfs

Comment: E esse é o resultado do método get: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/Bd90u-4

Comment: ele conecta sim na base

Comment: Então que pode ser? Pois não traz o resultado do where. Na verdade nesse teste eu coloquei where passando um id diretamente, mas o método vai fazer um like na campo Nome. Porém nenhuma das funções dá certo, nem passando diretamente no controller.

Comment: Você não está pedindo para que o resultado seja executado e montado é por causa disso precisa utilizar find ou findAll no final

Comment: Deu certo do jeito que falou, agradeço muito pela ajuda.

Comment: @Lucas Rondon. Recomendo a doc. Dei uma lida rápida e achei muito boa https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html#finding-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não precisa fazer isso que está querendo fazer no `model` pode utilizar diretamente os métodos que o modelo tem que é muito mais lógico e mais fácil para manutenção, apesar disso faltou chamar o método no final do `builder` dentro do seu método personalizado, exemplo:

```
//dentro do método
public function pesquisar($id)
{
    return $this->where('id', $id)->first();
}
$blog = new Blog();
$result = $blog->pesquisar(1);
```

ou

```
//fora do método
public function pesquisar($id)
{
    return $this->where('id', $id);
}
$blog = new Blog();
$result = $blog->pesquisar(1)->first();
```

a mesma coisa é feita assim:

```
$blog = new Blog();
$result = $blog->where('id', 2)->first();
```

se a buscar for feita diretamente na sua chave primária, então:

```
$blog = new Blog();
$result = $blog->find(2);
```

Comment: Ótimo, muito obrigado  pela dica, além de dar certo agora vou conseguir fazer um código mais limpo, muito obrigado mesmo.

Comment: @MarcosXavier não entendi a recomendação?

Comment: @novic mil perdões. Era pra comentar na pergunta, viajei. Vou colocar no local certo.